# What if the lead developers abandon Monero, like what happened to Boolberry?

Tags: development, core-development-team, boolberry

I noticed that CryptoZoidberg basically stopped updating Boolberry in late 2015, as seen here: https://github.com/cryptozoidberg/boolberry/commits/master. Since then, the currency has almost completely flopped.

What would happen if the same thing occurred in Monero? What if MoneroMooo and Fluffypony and the rest simply lost interest or had other sudden priorities, and walked away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that Monero forked away from the original creator to begin with i think that already sufficiently answers the question. If the devs all of a sudden up and walk off the job all at once, there will be others that will step up and pick up where they left off. Most of the code is opensource, and sure some services, domains, etc may be difficult to recover, there will be no problem with starting up new similarly named sites to continue Monero development and support. As long as Monero is seen as a useful tool, there will be people that will support Monero's ongoing existence.

Answer (score 5):

I think Monero's community is a lot bigger than Boolberry's and you would hope that others would step in and fill the breach, but there's no getting away from the fact it would be terrible for the coin were (m)any of the devs to just quit.  Indeed I believe one of the devs passed away last year.  That said, as the community grows in usage and popularity more devs have gotten involved. It will need to continue growing to get more devs interested but that hopefully won't be too hard - Bitcoin's inventor stepped away and that hasn't held it back.